# Boot up from RAID with new motherboard

Tags: boot, motherboard, raid

our computer was about to die (it beeped 5 times and then rebooted, AMI beep codes say that is a failing motherboard/cpu) so we decided to get a new motherboard and CPU, a `Gigabyte F2A88XM-DS2` with `AMD A6 7400K` CPU. Our old setup had a `RocketRAID 174x` with `RAID 5` on it and on the RAID was the bootup partition. Now when I have set up the new motherboard, put in the RocketRAID 174x, hooked up the RAID the motherboard does not recognise any boot partition.

I can get into the RAID BIOS and there everything looks fine, the RAID is recognised and seems ok, still the bootup wont work.

Any way to tell the motherboard to bootup from the RAID instead of looking for SATA disks?